Why is my UI not being updated even when the state of my List changes?
So I have the following Screen in my app -
fun TodoListPage(viewModel: TodoViewModel,
                 modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
                 navHost: NavHostController,
                 paddingValues: PaddingValues,
                 authViewModel: AuthViewModel ) {

    val todoList by viewModel.todoList.observeAsState()

    val user = authViewModel.user
    Log.d("User", user?.email.toString())

Column(modifier = modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(top = paddingValues.calculateTopPadding()),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        if (user!=null){
            Text(text = "User email - "+user.email.toString(), color = Color.Black)
        } else {
            Text(text = "Not Signed In", color = Color.Black)
        }
        todoList?.let {
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .wrapContentWidth(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                    .padding(top = paddingValues.calculateTopPadding())
            ) {
                itemsIndexed(it) { index:Int, todoItem: TodoItem ->
                    Item(Modifier.padding(15.dp),
                        todoItem,
                        onDelete = {
                            viewModel.deleteTodoItem(todoItem.id)
                        },
                        onEdit = {
                            navHost.navigate(route = "EditScreen?title=${todoItem.title}&description=${todoItem.description}&id=${todoItem.id}")
                        })
                }
            }
        }


}

In my view Model I have the following code -

class TodoViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private var _todoList = MutableLiveData<SnapshotStateList<TodoItem>>()
    var todoList : LiveData<SnapshotStateList<TodoItem>> = _todoList

    init {
        getAllToDo()
    }
    fun getAllToDo(){
        _todoList.value = TodoManager.getAllToDo()
        Log.d("TodoManager", "getAllToDo: ${todoList.value.toString()}")
    }
}

And in my Manager getAllToDo()
    fun getAllToDo(): SnapshotStateList<TodoItem> {

        val user = Firebase.auth.currentUser
        val tempList = SnapshotStateList<TodoItem>()

        user?.let {
            Firebase.firestore.collection(it.uid).get()
                .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
                    for (document in documents) {
                        val todoItem = document.toObject(TodoItem::class.java)
                        tempList.add(todoItem)

                    }
                    Log.d("TempList", "$tempList")
                    todoList = tempList
                    Log.d("TodoList", "$todoList")

                }
                
        }

        return todoList

    }

When I run my code, I get the following Log statements,

2024-06-10 19:44:50.675  3730-3730  TodoManager
2024-06-10 19:44:52.609  3730-3730  TempList
2024-06-10 19:44:52.609  3730-3730  TodoList

I wanted to understand how I should fix this, and why my UI is not getting updated after my todoList is updated.
I understand that the Manager runs first, and by that point the list is empty so my Screen is not populated, but once the query to get the data from firestore finishes, shouldn't the state change and the UI recompose?

SOLUTION
As some of the comments below had mentioned, since Firebase calls the data asynchronously I had to make my getAllToDo function a coroutine. Sharing my code and solution below incase it helps any future newbie like me.
Convert the getAllToDo function into a coroutine function so that it can run asynchronously.
    suspend fun getAllToDo(): SnapshotStateList<TodoItem> {
        val tempTodolist = SnapshotStateList<TodoItem>()
        try{
            Firebase.firestore
                .collection(Firebase.auth.currentUser!!.uid)
                .get()
                .await()
                .map{
                    val todoItem = it.toObject(TodoItem::class.java)
                    tempTodolist.add(todoItem)
                }
            todoList = tempTodolist
        } catch (e: Exception){
            Log.w("Firebase GET ERROR", "Error getting documents: ", e)
        }
        return todoList
    }

And then call it from my viewModel
    fun getAllToDo(){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _todoList.value = TodoManager.getAllToDo()
        }
        Log.d("TodoViewModel", "getAllToDo: ${todoList.value.toString()}")
    }


Using LiveData for new work is rather strange. Beyond that, is TodoListPage() recomposing? If it is, then the problem lies in TodoItem or your rendering code, neither of which are shown in your question.

@CommonsWare I have edited my code to show the TodoListPage rendering. It is a Composable and the code does work when I sign out and then log back in. As for the TodoItem, that is just a Data class

getAllTodoList() is wonky because it returns the previous value of todoList before it’s replaced in the firebase listener. It either needs to be changed to a suspend function that awaits the new value before returning it, or a callback-based function that passes the new value to a listener parameter instead of returning it. Remember that code inside a listener is called in the future. Read this question and answers to understand better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-or-launches-a-coroutine-return-an-empty-o

There is no way you can return that list as a result of a method. Firebase API is asynchronous. So please check the duplicates to see how you can solve this.

@Tenfour04, thanks for your comments! I was able to convert my function into a coroutine and it works now. I have edited my question and attached my solution with it too!

@AlexMamo thanks for your comments! I was able to convert my function into a coroutine and it works now. I have edited my question and attached my solution with it too!

Glad it helped. You also need to add a line inside your catch block: if (e is CancellationException) throw e. This is because CancellationExceptions are the way coroutines handle cancellation, so you cannot swallow them. Otherwise, the coroutine will hang when cancelled and become a memory and resource leak.
